# How to Connect Attendance Punching Machine Using zKemKeeper in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, biometrics, time-and-attendance

I am developing attendance software using asp.net c#, when iam trying to connect biometric device ( attendance punching machine ) using asp.net c# it shows the error

**Error:
"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."**

**My Code :**

```
//internal Axzkemkeeper.AxCZKEM AxCZKEM1;
    //public Axzkemkeeper.AxCZKEM axCZKEM1 = new Axzkemkeeper.AxCZKEM();
    //public zkemkeeper.CZKEM axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEM();
    //public delegate int DecompressMCX(int hComp,IntPtr in, uint in_len, IntPtr out, ref uint out_len, bool eod);

    public zkemkeeper.CZKEM axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEM();

private void Essl_Connect(string IpAddress, int MachineNo)
    {
        try
        {
            bConn = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(IpAddress.Trim(), 8080);
            //bConn = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(IpAddress.Trim(), 4370);
            if (bConn == true)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Message", "alert('Connected')", true);
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Message", "alert('Not Connected')", true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Error Message", "alert('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "')", true);
        }
    }
```

any one rectify this problem, is there any alternative way to connect the machine?..

if iam using

**public zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass();**

it shows the following Error:

"Interop type 'zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead."

Answer (score 3):

Change (in properties) of that dll interop.zkemkeeper, embed type to False.

Comment: This is the correct answer for me. It worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure regstr correct dll files x64/x32
2. add this code top of the code where class created

   [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]

Answer (score 0):

```
     public static CZKEM axCZKEM1 = new CZKEM();
    private static bool bIsConnected;
    private static int iMachineNumber;

    public static bool ConnectDevice(string IP,int Port)
    {
        int idwErrorCode=0;
        try
        {
            bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(IP.Trim(),Port);
            if (bIsConnected)
            {
                iMachineNumber = 1; //In fact,when you are using the tcp/ip communication,this parameter will be ignored,that is any integer will all right.Here we use 1.
                axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, false);
                axCZKEM1.RegEvent(iMachineNumber, 65535); //
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                axCZKEM1.GetLastError(idwErrorCode);
                new Exception($"Error : Unable to connect the device, ErrorCode =  {idwErrorCode}");
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public static bool DisconnectDevice()
    {
        try
        {
            axCZKEM1.Disconnect();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
```

Comment: Please describe your answer @mhmd.tuhami.

Answer (score -1):

1. Connect biometric attendance machine with .NET using C#.NET.
   Now write the code below on the connect button's click event.

   Declare your connection object first:

   ```
   public zkemkeeper.CZKEM axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEM();
   private void btnconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           bool bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(ip_address_of_your_machine, 4370);   // 4370 is port no of attendance machine
           if (bIsConnected == true)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Device Connected Successfully");
           }
           else
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Device Not Connect");
           }
       }

       Catch( (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
       }
   }
   ```
2. Download attendance log from biometric attendance machine in the database using C#.NET.

   Write the code below on the click event of the download attendance button:

   ```
   private bool IsRead = false;
   string dwEnrollNumber;
   int dwVerifyMode, dwInOutMode, dwYear, dwMonth, dwDay, dwHour, dwMinute, dwSecond,           dwWorkcode, dwMachineNumber;
   public zkemkeeper.CZKEM axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEM();

   public class ClsMachineBL
   {
       public String DownloadDataFromBiomatrix(ClsMachineML prp)
       {
           try
           {
               string constr = CommonConnection.ConStr;
               con = new SqlConnection(constr);
               con.Open();
               cmd = new SqlCommand("Prc_InsertDatafromBiomatrix", con);
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dwMachineNumber", prp.dwMachineNumber);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dwEnrollNumber", prp.dwEnrollNumber);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dwVerifyMode", prp.dwVerifyMode);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dwInOutMode", prp.dwInOutMode);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dwYear", prp.dwYear);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dwMonth", prp.dwMonth);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dwDay", prp.dwDay);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dwHour", prp.dwHour);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dwMinute", prp.dwMinute);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dwSecond", prp.dwSecond);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dwWorkcode", prp.dwWorkcode);
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               BL.clsCommon objerr = new BL.clsCommon();
               objerr.InesrtError("Error IS " + ex.Message + "_" + ex.StackTrace);
           }
           finally
           {
               cmd.Dispose();
               con.Close();
               con.Dispose();
           }
           return result;
       }
   }

   public class ClsMachineML
   {
       public string Id { get; set; }
       public string MachineNo { get; set; }
       public string MachineIP { get; set; }
       public string PortNo { get; set; }
       public string Remark { get; set; }
       public string Tuser { get; set; }
       public string Tdate { get; set; }
       public string Status { get; set; }
       public int  dwMachineNumber { get; set; }
       public string dwEnrollNumber { get; set; }
       public int dwVerifyMode { get; set; }
       public int dwInOutMode { get; set; }
       public int dwYear { get; set; }
       public int dwMonth { get; set; }
       public int dwDay { get; set; }
       public int dwHour { get; set; }
       public int dwMinute { get; set; }
       public int dwSecond { get; set; }
       public int dwWorkcode { get; set; }
       public string User_Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public int Finger_Index { get; set; }
       public string Finger_Image { get; set; }
       public int Privilege { get; set; }
       public string Passwords { get; set; }
       public bool Enabled { get; set; }
       public int Flag { get; set; }
       public string  Fromdate { get; set; }
       public string Todate { get; set; }
   }

   private void btndownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        ClsMachineBL obj = new ClsMachineBL();
        ClsMachineML prp = new ClsMachineML();

       try
       {
           if (cbmachine.Text == "" || cbmachine.Text == "Select")
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Please Select Machine");
               cbmachine.Focus();
               return;
           }

           progressBar1.Visible = true;
             bool bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(ip_address_of_your_machine, 4370);   // 4370 is port no of attendance machine
           if (bIsConnected == true)
           {
               IsRead = axCZKEM1.ReadGeneralLogData(dwMachineNumber);
               if (IsRead == true)
               {
                   progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
                   progressBar1.Step = 1;
                   progressBar1.Value = 0;
                   while (axCZKEM1.SSR_GetGeneralLogData(dwMachineNumber, out dwEnrollNumber, out dwVerifyMode, out dwInOutMode, out dwYear, out                                dwMonth, out dwDay, out dwHour, out dwMinute, out dwSecond, ref dwWorkcode))
                   {
                       prp.dwDay = dwDay;
                       prp.dwEnrollNumber = dwEnrollNumber;
                       prp.dwHour = dwHour;
                       prp.dwInOutMode = dwInOutMode;
                       prp.dwMachineNumber = dwMachineNumber;
                       prp.dwMinute = dwMinute;
                       prp.dwMonth = dwMonth;
                       prp.dwSecond = dwSecond;
                       prp.dwVerifyMode = dwVerifyMode;
                       prp.dwWorkcode = dwWorkcode;
                       prp.dwYear = dwYear;
                       string add = obj.DownloadDataFromBiomatrix(prp);
                       progressBar1.PerformStep();
                   }

                   string export = obj.ExportToAttendance(prp);
                   MessageBox.Show("Attendance Downloaded Successfully");
                   progressBar1.Visible = false;
               }
               else
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("No Log Found....");
                   progressBar1.Visible = false;
               }
           }
           else
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Device Not Connected");
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
       }
   }
   ```
3. Delete the attendance log from biometric attendance machine in the database using C#.NET.

   ```
   public zkemkeeper.CZKEM axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEM();
   private void btndownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       bool bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(ip_address_of_your_machine, 4370);   // 4370 is port no of attendance machine
       if (bIsConnected == true)
       {
           bool delete = axCZKEM1.ClearGLog(dwMachineNumber);
           if (delete == true)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Deleted.....");
           }
           if (delete == false)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("No Log Found To Delete.....");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I don't think `Catch( (Exception ex)` in your first code segment is syntactically correct.

Comment: thanks... could you please the code for the procedure Prc_InsertDatafromBiomatrix ?